# Where in this BNF grammar do match ; after 'end'

Tags: pascal, bnf

Reading [this](http://bernhard.userweb.mwn.de/Pascal-EBNF.html) Pascal BNF grammar I can't understand why is a `;` required to appear after `end` in a function definition. After a function-heading is seen, a `function-block` that's `block` may appear:

```
 function-declaration =
    function-heading ";" function-body |
    function-heading ";" directive |
    function-identification ";" function-body . 
function-body =
    block .
```

When a `begin` appear, that's part of a `statement-par`, that's part of a block, it's processed by `statement-part`, right?

```
 block =
    declaration-part statement-part . 
 statement-part =
    begin statement-sequence end .
```

Note `statement-part`. There's no `;` here after `end` keyword and this is not part of a `statement-sequence`. So, I don't get how the compiler claims about lack of `;` after `end` keyword, like in this example:

```
function myabs(i : integer) : integer;
begin
     if i < 0 then begin i := -i; end; < -- it's process by statement-sequence, so, ';' may appear
     myabs := i;
end; <-- it is the semicolon what about I'm speaking
```

What am I missing? am I reading wrong the grammar? all Pascal compilers I've tried give an error if I omit this.

Comment: In that very same link, it has the part that brings together the `function-declaration` and the `function-body`, namely:  `procedure-and-function-declaration-part = 
    { (procedure-declaration | function-declaration) ";" } .` That's where the semicolon is.

Comment: Why -1? donwvoter please explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to have a semi-colon after an end. Simple as that.

Semi-colon is used to separate statements. So you only need to have a semi-colon after an end if it is not the last statement. If it is the last statement you should instead have a full stop.

Now, there could also be some error in the BNF that means that according to the BNF you don't have to have a semi-colon where you actually need it, but the only way to figure that out is to analyze the whole BFN in detail, which I don't feel is constructive. :-)

But in this case I think what you have missed is that a [procedure or function declaration must end with a semi-colon](http://bernhard.userweb.mwn.de/Pascal-EBNF.html#procedure-and-function-declaration-part).

Comment: But why any Pascal compiler(all I've tried) say something like "expected ";" but something-else found"?

Comment: @TheMask Because it expected a semi-colon in that location, but it didn't find one. Make no mistake, there should be a semi-colon in the location you are asking about.

Comment: I had not seen you edit before. Thanks very much. :) Really, I've read all this programmer before and didn't notice that.

Answer (score 2):

ANTLRWorks is your best friend here.

If you try some pascal grammar such as http://www.monperrus.net/martin/pascal-antlr3 using antlrworks (http://www.antlr3.org/works/) you'll see that a program like

```
program first;
function myabs(i : integer) : integer;
begin
end;
begin
end.
```

will be parsed like this

[image]

so you can see exactly what's happening.

ps. the pascal grammar link I've provided to you has a problem with one specific token, but I bet you can workaround this ;-)

ps2. update - antlrworks screenshot to help @Jack

[image]

Comment: How did you created this diagram from an entire grammar? I can only create from the selected grammar (where mouse is on).

Comment: @Jack, do like this: open antlrworks 1.5.2, open the grammar (ctrl+O), paste the pascal snippet into the left text area (tab "interpreter"). "program" is selected by default in the select box above this left text area, then just click on the "play" icon. I've added a screenshot in the answer to help.

Answer (score 1):

Procedure and functions do not need to be terminated with a semi-colon, but they must be separated by one:

From [the Pascal BNF](http://www2.informatik.uni-halle.de/lehre/pascal/sprache/pas_bnf.html)

```
proc-and-func-declaration:  
   proc-or-func  
   proc-and-func-declaration ; proc-or-func
```